# How to Display Join table from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with querying data in MySQL, I want my data to display like this:

| id | Name | Kp | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KI014 | TPD | SS10 | 1000 |
|  |  | SS11 | 2000 |
|  |  | SS12 | 3000 |
| KI015 | ASD | SK14 | 1500 |
|  |  | SK15 | 2500 |

My query is like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS produkreseller.IDRESELLER as ID,
       masterreseller.NAMARESELLER as Name, 
       produk.KodeProduk as KP, 
       produkreseller.hargajual as Price 
FROM produkreseller 
INNER JOIN produk ON produkreseller.IdProduk = produk.IDPRODUK 
INNER JOIN masterreseller ON produkreseller.IDRESELLER = masterreseller.idreseller
ORDER BY masterreseller.idreseller;
```

And the result from that query is:

| id | Name | Kp | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KI014 | TPD | SS10 | 1000 |
| KI014 | TPD | SS11 | 2000 |
| KI014 | TPD | SS12 | 3000 |
| KI015 | ASD | SK14 | 1500 |
| KI015 | ASD | SK15 | 2500 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to partition the data by IDRESELLER, check if the current record is the first record in that partition, and if so, include the value of IDRESELLER (or NAMARESELLER) in the result, otherwise include the empty string.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY produkreseller.IDRESELLER) = 1 
            THEN produkreseller.IDRESELLER
            ELSE '' END as ID,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY produkreseller.IDRESELLER) = 1 
            THEN masterreseller.NAMARESELLER
            ELSE '' END as Name,
       produk.KodeProduk as KP, 
       produkreseller.hargajual as Price 
  FROM produkreseller 
 INNER JOIN produk ON produkreseller.IdProduk = produk.IDPRODUK 
 INNER JOIN masterreseller ON produkreseller.IDRESELLER = masterreseller.idreseller
 ORDER BY id;
```

This solution makes use of window function [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number). More information about window functions can be found in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).

**Update**

In MySQL 5 there are no window functions but one can make use of variables:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ID <> @last_id THEN ID ELSE '' END as ID,
       CASE WHEN ID <> @last_id THEN Name ELSE '' END as Name,
       KP, Price,
       @last_id := ID
  FROM (SELECT produkreseller.IDRESELLER as ID,
               masterreseller.NAMARESELLER as Name,
               produk.KodeProduk as KP,
               produkreseller.hargajul as Price
          FROM produkreseller
         INNER JOIN produk ON produkreseller.IdProduk = produk.IDPRODUK
         INNER JOIN masterreseller ON produkreseller.IDRESELLER = masterreseller.idreseller
         ORDER BY id) products, (SELECT @last_id := '') x;
```

As I don't have a possibility to run those queries, consider them as untested sketches (that is they may contain errors).

Comment: thanks for your replay, i'm try with your query  get this error :

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (PARTITION BY produkreseller.IDRESELLER) = 1
            THEN produkresell' at line 1

Mysql Version is 5.5 is still posibble use partition ?

Comment: @SpawnSheep, no, window functions were introduced in MySQL 8. I've updated my answer with a sketch for MySQL 5.